# Transfer a 'square' to another page into a grid view after button click

Tags: javascript, html, css, gridview, css-grid

I'm working on a project where a student or a school can add projects to search for collaborators.
I made a page where the user can fill in the details and next to the fields there is a preview square where the user can see how it will look.

After the user clicks on upload, the square should be seen on the homepage (the feed). All these squares should be in a grid layout with 3 or 4 squares per row.


Is there a way that i can transfer these squares with the filled in details to a gridlayout?

These squares also needs to be send to a database, but that's not necessary for now.


*The page where the user fills in the details*[image]


*The home page where the gridlayout(?) should be and where the square can be seen[image]*


*The code for the preview square*

```
<div class="preview">
        <div class="content">
            <h1 id="previewDate"></h1>
            <h1 id="previewTitle"></h1>
            <p id="previewDescription"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
            <button>See more</button>
            <p>Quick look</p>
        </div>
        <div class="aside">
            <div class="status">
                <img src="img/green.png" alt="status">
                <p>Open</p>
            </div>
            <div class="persons">
                <img src="img/Icon ionic-md-person.png" alt="persons">
                <p id="previewPersons"></p>
                <p>/</p>
                <p id="previewPersons2"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="hours">
                <img src="img/Icon awesome-clock.png" alt="time">
                <p id="previewHours"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You say "These squares also needs to be send to a database, but that's not necessary for now.", but it kind of is.

The normal flow would be:

- user does a something to create a "thing"
- "thing" is uploaded to the server
- on a different page, "thing" is pulled from the server and displayed

Now, if you are creating a SPA (single-paged app), you could keep "thing" in memory and show it on the other page when you switch over. The tags you listed don't indicate that you're using a SPA though (common SPA frameworks would be things like React, Vue, Angular or Lit/Polymer, though those aren't strictly SPAs and you don't need a framework for a SPA either).

Similarly, you could also store "thing" in [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API), [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API), or a cookie.

Though all of those will only be viewable on the user's computer, and probably not really what you want, and probably even more complicated than just getting it uploaded to the server.

You're likely putting the cart before the horse on this one, and getting it uploaded to the server first is going to make your life less complicated.

Comment: Ahh i see. Thanks for your answer, was really helpfull! The flow you are pointing out (uploading to server/pulling from server), can this be achieved with vanilla js?

Comment: The upload/download part, yes. The modern way is to use [fetch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API). The server part itself will, obviously, need to be a server, which could be written in Node.js if you want to stick with JS (check out [Express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express)) or just about any other language.

Comment: Just to note, made a tweak clarifying that both the SPA stuff and the storage options all would only affect the client. Only uploading to a server would allow it to be shared.

Comment: Hi man, sorry but could u help me some more? Looked up a lot, but can't seem to figure out where to start. There is already a MySql database with some tables. Now looking at the flow; when user created 'thing' and clicks 'upload', i need to send the thing (with all components e.g. title, description etc.) to the database (which i can achieve with vanilla js (?)) and after uploading it to the database i can retrieve it again with only vanilla js and place it in a grid view, which will populate more when user creates more 'things'. How would this all be handled? What should be the proper way?

Comment: I'm learning js and following some courses, so i'm kinda new. Especially when it comes to backend

Comment: That's a pretty big topic, but basically you'll need to implement the C(reate) and R(ead) and maybe U(pdate) parts of a CRUD backend, to get and save (POST) the data to the server. Your server will be what reads and writes to the database. If you want to stick with JS, you'll want to make your backend in Node.js, probably using Express, so I'd google around for something like "node.js crud express mysql" and look at some tutorials.